# How do I add a date column and integer column together using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two columns in a database once called purchase_date and the other called lifetime.  I am trying to filter the results so that only the assets that are not passed their lifetime are shown when given the current tax year.

I've tried

```
Asset.where("? < DATE_ADD(purchase_date,INTERVAL lifetime YEAR) AND  purchase_date >= ?",Date.new(2012,1,1),Date.new(2012,1,1))
```

But, then I realized that this would be tied to MySQL if it did work, which is fine if this was just going to work with my full aplication.  But, I want something that is database agnostic especially since this is being tested against Sqlite.  Sqlite with this query gives me the following exception:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near lifetime

How can I add an integer column to a date column in my sql statement in an database agnostic way?

**Update**

I have played around with Squeel, but I don't think its going to work.   It may be possible  to detect the adapter and base it off of that.

Comment: maybe squeel can help you, but not Arel I'm afraid

Comment: @user1737909 thanks for the input.  I am trying it know,  but for some reason I am getting a wrong number of arguments exception 0 for 1.

Comment: 0 for 1 exception is gone.  I thought that it was either because I had to generate an initializer in my dummy app or I had to add a development dependency to my gemspec.  Note: this is a rails engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add an `:expires_at` field?  You can set a :before_save hook to make sure it's automatically kept in sync with your `:lifetime` field.

```
before_save :set_expiration_date

scope :not_expired, where("expires_at > ?", DateTime.now)

def set_expiration_date
  return unless purchase_date.changed? || lifetime.changed?
  self.expires_at = purchase_date + lifetime.years
end
```